# How to initialize a constant with non breakable space character?

Tags: vb.net, encoding, character-encoding, constants

I have this code written in c# and it is valid and working.

```
public const char NBSP = '\u00A0';
```

For some reasons I need to write this method in VB.net. I tried these:

1.

```
Public Const NBSP As Char = "\u00A0"
```

Error: `Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Char'`

2.

```
Public Const NBSP As Char = "\u00A0"c
```

Error: `Character constant must contain exactly one character.`

3.

```
Public Const NBSP As Char = &HA0 'Or 0x00A0
```

Error: Integer values can not be converted to Char.

Note: I can not use `ChrW()` function. Neither `Convert.ToChar()` as it is a Const. One solution may be removing the Const key, but looks ugly to me.

I am thinking that I should use String instead of Char datatype. But not sure if it may cause any issues?

```
Public Const NBSP As String = "\u00A0"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different methods.

Using an Integer to store the value, then convert it to `char` using [ChrW()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chrw):

```
Dim nbs1 As Integer = &HA0
Console.WriteLine("NBS" & New String({ChrW(nbs1)}))
```

Using a Byte array and calling [Encoding.Unicode.GetString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring) to conver the byte array to a string. Note that the byte order is inverted:

```
Dim nbs2 As Byte() = {&HA0, &H0}
Console.WriteLine("NBS" & Encoding.Unicode.GetString(nbs2))
```

Using [Regex.Unescape()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape) to convert the unicode escaped char "\uXXXX" to a string:

```
Dim nbs3 As String = "\u00A0"
Dim nbs4 = "NBS" & Regex.Unescape(nbs3)
Console.WriteLine(nbs4)
```